# Oracle query concatenate date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
select * 
  from mytable 
 where to_char(mydate,'mm/dd/yyyy') between ('05/23/2013') 
                                        and ('06/22/2013')
```

I need to change it to make dynamically so that I won't modify it every month from `05/23/2013` to `06/23/2013` for example:

```
('05/23/' + (select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy') from dual))
```

but this is giving an error. Any suggestions?

**What I need to do:** Every month I need to run this query to get the records between 23<sup>rd</sup> of this month and 23<sup>rd</sup> of the last month.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do in words? The current description doesn't make sense -- why would you change the year value every month?

Comment: every month i need to run this query to get the records between 23 of this month and 23 of the last month

Comment: If today is 2013-05-12, what is the earliest date and time you would want to be included, and what is the latest date and time?

Comment: it is always from 22 this month to 23 of last month

Comment: "From" is the earliest, so from 23 of last month to 22 of this month inclusive?

Comment: yes exactly, how to do this, taking into consideration that "mydate" is Date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle uses `||` as the [concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm):

```
('05/23/' || (select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy') from dual))
```

BTW, David is right. If you really want to compare string representations of dates (but why?), use a date format that is ordered the same way as dates:

```
to_char(mydate,'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Answer (score 4):

You're performing a comparison on strings, not on dates, so your code doesn't work the way you think it does.

Based on the string logic, "05/23/2000" is between "05/22/2013" and "06/24/2000".

Keep the data types as date and Oracle will get the comparison right.

Possibly what you want is:

```
select *
from   my_table
where  mydate >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-1)+22 and
       mydate <  trunc(sysdate,'MM')+22
```

but it's difficult to tell without a description of what the requirement actually is.

Comment: Ok, tweaked it to do "greater then or equal to 23rd of last month and less than 23rd of this month" in case you have a time component on the date

Comment: no errors, but not getting the same number of records as the static method

Comment: Are they the correct rows? Test for other dates by substituting (date '2013-02-02') instead of sysdate

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
SELECT '(''05/23/'''||to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')||'''' FROM DUAL
```

Have not testet because I have no Oracle database right now, needs checking for quote escapes...

Do you need exact days from the month? You can also substract days from sysdate:

```
SELECT (sysdate - 30) FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use concat function

```
concat('05/23/', (select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy') from dual))
```